# JQuery Issue Code, Trying To click a button programmatically but it isn't work - No id/class

Tags: jquery

Heres my current attempt:

```
<div class="links">
    <a href="/login">Login</a>
    <a href="/register">Register</a>
</div>
```

My JQuery For This Attempt Is:

```
setTimeout (
  function()
  {
    alert("Clicking Now");
    $('.links a:contains("Register")').trigger('click');
  }, 2000);
```

This doesn't seem to click the href link after 2 seconds... Any help please?

Comment: Are you expecting the logical click to invoke a page transfer to the link's url?

Comment: I tried it in JS fidde and it does work. https://jsfiddle.net/939j8fsu/

Comment: Yes, my full intention is to be able to do this and apply it to a iframe's code

Comment: @superbAfterSemperPhi It doesn't invoke the page transfer.

Comment: It's a slight security concern if page logic could replicate a user click for a page transfer.  IIRC you have to do a redirect for this type of functionality, as Bricky mentions below.

Comment: How would I redirect the <iframe>?

Comment: Inside the iframe, you'd change it's window.location.  From the parent you'd change it's src attribute.

Comment: You can also get into the scope of an iframe nested in the page without changing the `src`, that way you maintain history and some other data. `document.getElementById('targetFrame').contentWindow.someFunction()` or in this case `$('iframe)[0].contentWindow.location.href = '/login'`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a built in function `$(el).click()` try using that first.

Certain browsers limit your ability to do actions that would typically have to be taken by the user (click, copy, paste), but you can still trigger/broadcast the events so that anything triggered by an eventListener can pick it up.

For this particular goal, I think it would be more appropriate to redirect the user to your login page, using something like `window.location.href = '/login'`

Comment: the el, if it is a link, would also have a native click method, without using jQuery

Comment: @Bricky I want it to automatically click it after 2 seconds

Comment: @RuneStake you can redirect them after 2 seconds by changing the href in your current `setTimeout`. Is your goal to redirect the user to the login page, or is your goal to click the button? jQuery's `$.click()` will trigger all of the event handlers and tracking as if it were clicked, but may not redirect them. Changing the href will redirect the page, but will not trigger click events. You can use both together for reliability if needed.